# How to find largest property in List?

Tags: c#

I have linq expression "Where" that may returns several rows:

```
var checkedPrices = prices.Where(...).ToList();
```

As there are several rows, retrieves from db => i want to take the largest string from this list of rows.

Also there is a case when one of the fields may have same lenght, so i tried to find the largest from another field.

```
int countPrices = checkedPrices.Count();

if (checkedPrices == 0)
{
    checkedPrices = null;
}
else if (checkedPrices == 1) 
{
    checkedPrices = checkedPrices.Take(1).ToList();
}
else if (countFixedPrices > 1)
{
    var maxPrices1 = checkedPrices.Max(i => i.Field1.Length);
    if (maxPrices1 > 1)
    {
        var maxPrices2 = checkedPrices.Max(i => i.Field2.Length);
        checkedPrices = checkedPrices.IndexOf(maxPrices2 );
    }

    checkedPrices = checkedPrices .ElementAt(maxPrices2);
}
```

So, i have an issue in the last "else if".
My logic was to find the max largest of Field1.
If there is the only one largest field - rewrite it to the "Where" expression (checkedPrices).
If there is not only one max largest of Field1 => take the largest from Field2.

The problem of mine is i'm confused how could i take the row data from the largest Field1/Field2.

This part of code is ridiculously bad(doesnt even compile):

```
if (maxPrices1 > 1)
{
    var maxPrices2 = checkedPrices.Max(i => i.Field2.Length);
    checkedPrices = checkedPrices.IndexOf(maxPrices2 );
}

checkedPrices = checkedPrices .ElementAt(maxPrices2);
```

Comment: `var checkedPrices.OrderBy(p => p.Field1.Length).ThenBy(p => p.Field2.Length).First()` maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems you need only one price I would recommend just write correct query to fetch it only. You can order items (with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)'s [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0) and [`ThenByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending?view=net-6.0)) and the take the top one:

```cs
var checkedPrice = prices
    .Where(...)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Field1.Length)
    .ThenByDescending(c => c.Field2.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

P.S:

- For LINQ-to-Objects this solution can be inefficient for large datasets after filtering due to sorting being O(n * log(n)) operation while finding maximum element is O(n) task.
- There can be implementation depended LINQ optimizations for some of cases like combination of `OrderBy(Descending)` with some overloads of operators like `First(OrDefault)` and possibly `Skip`/`Take` (see [one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/2401), [two](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14867), [three](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/orderby-firstordefault-complexity-increase)).

Comment: May be good idea to note that this may be poor choice for non-SQL based enumerables with large number of elements. MaxBy with custom comparer (.Net6+) or custom code to find max in linear time may be better option.

Comment: (Also presumably you sort by different fields - not really sure if current sorting by the same filed twice is of any use... except from OP)

Comment: I'm with @AlexeiLevenkov. Sorting is an O( N log(N)) operation. Going for an O (N) solution is a better idea if it's a large dataset

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov as for sorting on the same field - it was a typo. OP sorts based on two. As for complexity - I thought that since 3.1 ordering followed by `First`/`Last` was [optimized](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/2401) to be O(n). Though it maybe does not cover the case of multiple sorts.

Comment: @Flydog57 I agree. Please see the update and comment for Alexei Levenkov